# Setup git over http/https with apache 2.4 server

Tags: git, apache2.4

I am trying to setup a git server behind apache 2.4 but could´t get it to work. I tried following all the tips I found here but didn´t find a working configuration for linux. I did find a working configuration for windows but when I tried to adapt it, it still fails.

The idea is to access the repositories from https://example.com/git/test.git

This is the part of my apache2.conf relevant to my git configuration:

```
<Directory "/var/www/kh_webserver/git">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Git Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/git.passwds
Require valid-user
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/kh_webserver/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL true
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
                info/refs | \
                objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                         [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                         pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                "/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1"


<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/git.passwds
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-upload-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/git.passwds
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Can somebody point me out where I am going wrong here? Thanks

My root directory in the web server is /var/www/kh_webserver
and I have the git repositories (for example test.git) in /var/www/kh_webserver/git

Comment: I am sorry I don't have an answer for you but a suggestion only - have you thought about using [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does look good. But I still want to learn how to set this up (this is just for learning and personal projects). I thought it would be more straight forward like setting up svn over apache. But every guide I found and tried to setup git over apache fails

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but you might want to see an entry I wrote on my Wiki about how to do this.

http://wiki.flat.cl/index.php?title=Git,_Apache_and_HTTPS_with_a_free_certificate

Hope it helps.